# Spring Boot CrudRepository or JpaRepository - how to pass limit as argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have repository interface which extends `CrudRepository`:

```
public interface ExampleRepository extends CrudRepository<Example, Long>{
    List<Example> findByValidIsTrueLimit(Integer limit);
}
```

I want to limit list of results to a specified limit like with `limit` in SQL query.

However I get:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'exampleRepository': Invocation of init
>   method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   Failed to create query method public abstract No property limit found
>   for type

How to add limit passed as argument to `CrudRepository` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From spring doc ([Limiting query results](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result)):

> The results of query methods can be limited via the keywords first or top, which can be used interchangeably. An optional numeric value can be appended to top/first to specify the maximum result size to be returned. If the number is left out, a result size of 1 is assumed.

So, for fixed limit `N` you can use `List<Example> findTopNByValidIsTrue()`

For variable value of limit you should use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#repositories.special-parameters):

```
Page<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
List<Example> result = repository.findByValidIsTrue(new PageRequest(0, N)).getContent();
```

Comment: getContent() is not necessary, you can retrieve List<Example> directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Pageable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Pageable.html) and it will give you a `Page<T>` then you can get the requested data from it.

```
 Page<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable pageable);
```

then call it using [PageRequest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html):-

```
    PageRequest req = new PageRequest(0,10); // I just want 10 record
    Page<Example> page =  findByValidIsTrue(req )
    List<Example> nRecords = page.getContent();
```

---

**Note**: If you don't pass the `PageRequest` object while calling `findByValidIsTrueLimit`, by default,it will give you first 20 records.

Comment: getContent() is not necessary, you can retrieve List<Example> directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a `Pageable` to the method signature. E.g.

`List<Example> findByValidIsTrue(Pageable p);`

Usage:

`List<Example> ex = repo.findByValidIsTrue(new PageRequest(0, 10));`